# Question about the complement

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $E=\{(x,y):x\in\mathbb{R},y\in(-\infty,0)\}$, what is the complement of $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Is $E^c=\phi\times[0,+\infty)$?Is this an empty set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give a bit more detail than DonAntonio's answer contains.

Recall the definition of complement in a given universe of discourse $U$:

$$E^c \stackrel{\rm def}= \{u \in U: u \notin E\}$$

In our case, $U = \Bbb R^2$, so we're looking to describe:

$$E^c = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: (x,y)\notin E\}$$

Now, the definition of $E$ stipulates that $(x,y) \in E$ precisely when $x \in \Bbb R$ **and** $y \in (-\infty,0)$.

So $(x,y) \in E^c$ when **not both $x \in \Bbb R$ and $y \in (-\infty,0)$**. That is, when $x \notin \Bbb R$ **or** $y \notin (-\infty,0)$. (Note how **and** became **or** by negating the statement.)

Since $x \in \Bbb R$ by definition, it remains to conclude that:

$$(x,y) \in E^c \text{ precisely when } y \notin (-\infty,0)$$

That is to say:

$$E^c = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: y \ge 0\} = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: y \in [0,\infty)\}$$

Comment: Thanks, these are very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The complement is

$$E^c=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\;;\;y\in[0,\infty)\}$$

the half upper plane including the $\:x-$axis